# How to generate random keys for dictionary values?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashcode

I have to randomly generate keys for dictionary using hashcode. I am unable to figure out the way to this problem. The dictionary key I have mentioned is 1,2,3,4 which needs to be auto generated.

```
d = {1:{'fname':['B'],
'parent' : ['A'],
 'child': ['C','D']},
2:{ 'fname' : ['C'],
'parent' : ['B'],
'child' : ['C1','C2']},
   3: { 'fname' : ['D'],
 'parent' : ['B'],
  'child': ['D1','D2']},
    4:{ 'fname' : ['C1'],
            'parent' : ['C'],
            'child': ['X']}}
```

Comment: How are you going to ensure key uniqueness if you generate them randomly?

Comment: Please update your question with code which shows an attempt at solving this. You could write something which contains the line: `d[make_hash_code()] = obj` and then you can ask how `def make_hash_code():` should be written.

Answer (score 1):

Random key generation, as mentioned will not be useful because can result in duplicate keys.

However, one of the interim solution to your problem with `auto incremented keys` is:

```
>>> dic = dict()
>>> dic
{}
>>> n=int(input("Enter the total number of dictionary items to be entered: "))
Enter the total number of dictionary items to be entered: 3

>>> for k in range(n):
...     dic[k]=input("Enter the value for "+str(k)+": ")
...
Enter the value for 0: {'fname':['B'],'parent' : ['A'],'child': ['C','D']}
Enter the value for 1: {'fname':['C'],'parent' : ['B'],'child': ['C1','C2']}
Enter the value for 2: {'fname':['D'],'parent' : ['B'],'child': ['D1','2']}
>>> dic
{0: {'parent': ['A'], 'fname': ['B'], 'child': ['C', 'D']}, 
1: {'parent': ['B'], 'fname': ['C'], 'child': ['C1', 'C2']}, 
2: {'parent': ['B'], 'fname': ['D'], 'child': ['D1', '2']}}
```

You can also put in your methods of adding the dictionary values instead of user input.